# Pass values from User Control (MVC 2, Json)

Tags: c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

these are the following technologies i am utilizing in my current project:
 - WCF
 - MVC 2
 - Json

I'm just new with MVC 2 and Json. My question is, how do you pass values from a User Control back to the page where it was called?

Please answer my question or give me any reference links wherein i can extract ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some code for us to look at? You want to pass a value from your (Partial?) View to your Layout?

Comment: As of now, i don't have any code to give. I just have my user control which appears as a pop-up and what it does is it searches users from the active directory. What i want to do is to pass the retrieved user info in the user control back to the main page.

Comment: Since we have no code, I am taking a stab here. In your controller, you can create a JSON string representation of the data and pass it on to your view.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, Keep the user details in session when your user control finds a user. then access that session variable from your controller or any place of your application.

```
//After your user controller find the User
Session.add("userName",UserNameProperty);

from your controller//
if(Session("userName") != null){
  string _uName = Session("userName").ToString()
// Do your logic
}
```